# Can C*-envelope introduce the unity?

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a non-unital Banach $*$-algebra with isometric involution. Is it possible that the enveloping $C^*$-algebra of $A$ is unital? I guess not at least when $A$ admits an approximate identity, but I can't prove it.